# helm template won't recognize variables

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

I'm trying to write a helm yaml template doing the following:

`My-deployment-template.yaml`:

```
{{- if eq $.Values.value "6" -}}
{{- $var1 := (toString $.Values.something6) -}}
{{- $var2 := (toString $.Values.somethingelse6) -}}
{{- else if eq $.Values.value "7"  -}}
{{- $var1 := (toString $.Values.something7) -}}
{{- $var2 := (toString $.Values.somethingelse7) -}}
{{- end }} 
...
... (in the same file )
{{- ..... |replace "Placeholder1" $var1 | replace "Placeholder2" $var2 }}}`
```

but the `$var1` and `$var2` are not recognized outside of the `if` scope I've created.  How can i overcome this issue ?

When I use `helm upgrade...` I get the following:

```
undefined variable "$var1" ...
undefined variable "$var2" ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of approaches to this problem as you've laid it out.

The Go [`text/template`](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) language supports assignment without creating a new variable `$var = value` (`=`, not `:=`).  This was new in [Go 1.11](https://go.dev/doc/go1.11), but that release has been out for over three years now, and most tools including Helm should incorporate it.  So you can create the variable outside the `if` block and then change it inside.

```
{{- $var1 := "" -}}

{{- if eq $.Values.value "6" -}}
{{- $var1 = (toString $.Values.something6) -}}
{{- end }}

{{- ... | replace "Placeholder1" $var1 | ... -}}
```

As you've shown the code, all of the values have similar names.  If this is true globally then you can construct the name once and use the standard template `index` function to look it up.  This would let you avoid the `if` block entirely.

```
{{- $var1name := printf "something%s" $.Values.value -}}
{{- $var1 := index $.Values $var1name | toString -}}
```

If you can restructure your values, then using a YAML map instead of a list of similarly-named values could be easier.

```yaml
# values.yaml
value: "6"
something:
  "6": foo
```

```
{{- $var1 := index $.Values.something $.Values.value | toString -}}
```

Finally, rather than having multiple sets of configuration in a single values file and trying to switch between them, if you can restructure things to keep only one set of configuration in a file, that's best still.  You can use the `helm install -f` option to provide additional configuration when you install the chart.

```
{{/* templates/foo.yaml */}}
{{ ... | replace "Placeholder1" .Values.something | ... }}
```

```yaml
# values.yaml

# something specifies the value used for `Placeholder1`.
something: a reasonable default used it nothing else is specied
```

```yaml
# values6.yaml, which could be outside the chart directory
something: the sixth per-environment value
```

```bash
helm install -f values6.yaml ...
```

(In other questions I've seen setups like this for dev/qa/prod environments, for example.  This `helm install -f` approach both makes it very clear what values are used in production and simplifies the template logic quite a bit.)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time, I've implemented the variable reassignment that you've showed, which now passes the helm upgrade without errors, but the block of "if-else if" i've written seems to lead to uncreachable code..